# Are files created with the FileHandle API compatible with the Device Storage API?

Tags: firefox-os

I would like to put a big file I have created using the FileHandle API (mozCreateFileHandle) in the device storage on my app.

I know the file is correct, because, from the dev console, printing the file yields the value below and the file at mozFullPath contains what I want.

```
File { size: 802860, type: "audio/wav", name: "clip-1.wav", path: "", 
lastModifiedDate: Date 2014-05-26T12:19:55.544Z, 
mozFullPath: "/home/laaglu/.mozilla/firefox/vk1ef0sn.aurora/extensions/fxos_1_4_simulator@mozilla.org/profile/storage/persistent/1003+f+http+++127.0.0.1+2345/idb/2300299066deincothap/2" }
```

However, when I try to put the file in storage using:

```
var myFile = ...;
var storage = navigator.getDeviceStorage('music');
var addNamedReq = storage.addNamed(myFile, 'clip-1.wav');
```

the addNamed method invokes onerror. The supplied error object does not contain further clues as to what goes wrong, such as error message, error code or stack trace. If I add a file created with new Blob(), addNamedReq succeeds.

My question are:

- has somebody already used this pattern successfully and if so can you
  please give advice as to what may be wrong ?
- is this a bug or limitation to a scenario that should normally work and should I file
  a Mozilla bug report for this ?

Answer (score 0):

At present, no. You can only create Blobs and write them all at one go. The bug tracking this is 859696: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=859696